# import hue workflow another cluster

Tags: cloudera, hue

I am importing a workflow from other cluster, to avoid conclicts I follow :

1. I modify the workflow json  "pk": 0
2. I delete dependencies : []
3. I change 'parent_directory' for the new cluster

By this way it imports in hue the new one workflow and a lot of copies with name+timestamp . How can i avoid this problem?

Comment: Have you tried from the Hue home page and the import/export buttons? http://gethue.com/exporting-and-importing-oozie-workflows/

Comment: Only works in the same cluster, when is a diferent cluster fails. Because 'parent_directory' is diferent, the only way to know this code is importing a sample workflow from that cluster (production) and setting the param in a workflow that you want deploy.